# How to fix RGB / RGBA colors not being shown as colors in neovim nvChad lazy.nvim colorizer plugin?

Tags: neovim, lua, color, plugin, nvchad

```
I can see color on those:
#000000
red


But not on those:
rgb(0,45,65);
rgba(2,45,23,1);
```

Here is `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\nvim\lua\plugins\init.lua` file colorizer code that comes preinstalled with nvChad:

```
  {
    "NvChad/nvim-colorizer.lua",
    init = function()
      require("core.utils").lazy_load "nvim-colorizer.lua"
    end,
    config = function(_, opts)
      require("colorizer").setup(opts)

      -- execute colorizer as soon as possible
      vim.defer_fn(function()
        require("colorizer").attach_to_buffer(0)
      end, 0)
    end,
  },
```

I don't know how to configure it.
Ive seen people try to add this:

```
 local custom_options = {
      mode = "background", -- You can change the mode to "foreground" to colorize foreground color codes
      RGB = true, -- Enable RGB color notation support
      RRGGBB = true, -- Enable RRGGBB color notation support
      names = false, -- Disable color name highlighting (e.g., "red", "blue", etc.)
      css = false, -- Disable CSS color notation support
    }
```

But I don't know lua and couldn't find any way to add those settings to it.

Comment: Did the solution provided solved your problem? How can we help you further? If it does may be could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It all the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adapt the `nvim/lua/custom/plugins.lua`
And make sure the `plugins` table contains the following section:

```
  {
    "NvChad/nvim-colorizer.lua",
    opts = {
        filetypes = { "*" },
        user_default_options = {
          RGB = true, -- #RGB hex codes
          RRGGBB = true, -- #RRGGBB hex codes
          names = true, -- "Name" codes like Blue or blue
          RRGGBBAA = false, -- #RRGGBBAA hex codes
          AARRGGBB = false, -- 0xAARRGGBB hex codes
          rgb_fn = true, -- CSS rgb() and rgba() functions
          hsl_fn = false, -- CSS hsl() and hsla() functions
          css = false, -- Enable all CSS features: rgb_fn, hsl_fn, names, RGB, RRGGBB
          css_fn = false, -- Enable all CSS *functions*: rgb_fn, hsl_fn
          -- Available modes for `mode`: foreground, background,  virtualtext
          mode = "background", -- Set the display mode.
          -- Available methods are false / true / "normal" / "lsp" / "both"
          -- True is same as normal
          tailwind = false, -- Enable tailwind colors
          -- parsers can contain values used in |user_default_options|
          sass = { enable = false, parsers = { "css" }, }, -- Enable sass colors
          virtualtext = "■",
          -- update color values even if buffer is not focused
          -- example use: cmp_menu, cmp_docs
          always_update = false
        },
        -- all the sub-options of filetypes apply to buftypes
        buftypes = {},
    }
  },
```